# Angular JS unknown Provider error - $cookieStoreProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an angular application. It was a working application on windows. 
Now i switched to mac and trying to build the same but after the build when I am opening the application on browser it is throwing console error: **Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]**

> https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$cookieStoreProvider%20%3C-%20$cookieStore

Here is the app.js:

```
 angular
        .module('xyz', [
            'ui.router',
            'Commons' ,
            'ngCookies',
            'ngMask',
            'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker',
            'btorfs.multiselect',
            'oitozero.ngSweetAlert'
        ])
        .constant('GLOBAL_CONSTANTS', {
        })
        .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', initializeConfigurationPhase])
        .run(['$rootScope', '$cookieStore', 'httpService', 'notificationService', initializeRunPhase]);

function initializeRunPhase($rootScope, $cookieStore, httpService, notificationService) {
    $rootScope.currentItem = 0;
    $rootScope.baseUrl = "someurl";
    // $rootScope.baseUrl = "http://localhost";
    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
    if($cookieStore.get('access_token')) {
        $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
        notificationService.connect();
    }


    if(!$cookieStore.get('userCountryCode')) {
        fetchUserCountry();
    } else {
         $rootScope.userCountryCode = $cookieStore.get('userCountryCode');
    }
    function fetchUserCountry () {
        httpService.getWithoutData(url, true).then(function(response){

            $cookieStore.put('userCountryCode',response.country_code);
            $cookieStore.put('city',response.city);
            $cookieStore.put('region_name',response.region_name);
        });
    }

}
```

Let me know if i am missing something or doing something wrong.

Comment: check libs versions. Latest https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies > $cookies.

Comment: why your `$cookieStore` is injected in run function

Comment: @PetrAveryanov angular-cookies#1.7.8

Comment: @Edison in run phase i am doing some cookie value check.

Comment: angularjs application run on your browser, it shouldn't depend on your os.
Are you sure nothing has changed?

Comment: yes, i just cloned the repo and did npm instal and then bower install.

Comment: can you post the **initializeRunPhase** function?
Or, even better, tell us where the repo is.
By the way here is an exemple with $cokieStore (check on your mack if it works :))

Comment: @IsraGab added.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov thanks Man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said by @Petr Averyanov,  $cookieStore is deprecated from angular 1.6
look [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/guide/migration)

> $cookieStore is now deprecated as all the useful logic has been moved
>   to $cookies, to which $cookieStore now simply delegates calls.

install angular 1.5 and you won't get that error

Comment: Worked! In windows bower install picked angular 1.5 version, but in mac it picked 1.7 version. That was the difference. Thanks a lot guys for your help.